# Showing directly a sequence in $\Bbb R^5$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Given the following vectors in $\Bbb R^5$

$\vec x_1 = (1,3,5,7,9)$   
$\vec x_2 = (2,4,6,8,10)$  
$\vec x_3 = (11,12,0,0,1)$ 
$\vec x_{k+3} = \frac 13(\vec x_{k+3} + \vec x_{k+1} + \vec x_k)$ $\forall k \in \Bbb N$

I need to show that {$\vec x_k$}$_k$ is convergent.

The hint our professor gave us for this problem was to use nested triangles and since this is a bounded sequence there exists a convergent subsequence, but I'm not sure how to define a triangle in $\Bbb R^5$.

Any pointers here are appreciated!

Comment: Three noncollinear points in $\Bbb R^5$ define a plane and so a triangle in that plane.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec x_{k+3} = \frac 13(\vec x_{k+2} + \vec x_{k+1} + \vec x_k)$ means that $\vec x_{k+3}$ is an *affine* combination of $\vec x_{k+2},\vec x_{k+1}, \vec x_k$ and so lies in the plane defined by them. This implies that that plane remains fixed.

$\vec x_{k+3} = \frac 13(\vec x_{k+2} + \vec x_{k+1} + \vec x_k)$ means that $\vec x_{k+3}$ is a *convex* combination of $\vec x_{k+2},\vec x_{k+1}, x_k$ and so lies in the triangle defined by them. The next point will define a smaller triangle, hence the nested triangles.